# Design time layout differs from runtime layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

The following code aligns the layout to the right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="230dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp" 
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtData"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape1"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#fafafa">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgData"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/data"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The adapter code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem1, parent, false);
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
textView.setText("Testing");
return rowView;
```

The listview is placed in some LinearLayout. None of them has `gravity` settings.

The listview xml:

```
<ListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/list1"
android:layout_weight="1"                      
/>
```

In design time, the item is well placed in the right:

[image]

In runtime, it is on the left side:

[image]

What else should I set?

Comment: @aegean Corrected, it was a typo.

Comment: ok, the layout you are infating (listitem1.xml) is what you shared at your question, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. I look for gravity modifiers, but there is no other.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your listview is aligined to left. Set its width to wrap and align it to right

Comment: If application has no gravity it defaults to align its content to left. Please specify gravity to right and it should work.